# More generic TryParse() of line of a PLY file

Tags: c#, parsing, inheritance, architecture

I'm building an import function to load an [PLY File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_%28file_format%29) into my program. The part I'm unsure about is the implementation of the Face-Parser. Such a face might come in two different versions, Face3 (connecting 3 vertices) or Face4 (connecting 4 vertices). In the *.ply file, they might look like this:

Face 3:

> 3 0 1 2 3

Face 4:

> 4 0 1 2 3

I created a class for both of them, implementing the interface `IFace`. The interface, however, can't define a method `TryParse()`, since I'd like to have it static. So each of the `Face` classes implement their own `TryParse` method and an additional `TryParse` to return an `IFace` instead of `Face3` or `Face4`. From a few points those methods are mostly the same. The way the `TryParse` is implementated at the moment (2 methods in 2 different classes) feels very clumsy. Is there a better way to solve this?

This is how I'm using it at the moment:

```
foreach (string line in faceLines)
{
    IFace face = new Face3();              // ugly: I need to instanciate the face bevore I can use "out face"
    var segments = lines[i].Split(' ');    // ugly: I'd rather not touch the line at all. TryParse should do everything

    switch (segments[0])                   // ugly! 
    {
        case "3":
            if (Face3.TryParse(lines[i], out face)) faces.Add((Face4)face);             
            break;
        case "4":
            if (Face4.TryParse(lines[i], out face)) faces.Add((Face4)face);    
            break;
    }
}
```

And here are `IFace`, `Face3` and `Face4`:

```
public interface IFace
{
    string ToString();        
}       

public struct Face3 : IFace
{
    public int V1;
    public int V2;
    public int V3;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("3 {0} {1} {2}", V1, V2, V3);
    }

    internal static bool TryParse(string Input, out IFace Face)
    {
        Face3 face = new Face3();
        bool b = TryParse(Input, out face);

        Face = (IFace)face;
        return b;
    }

    internal static bool TryParse(string Input, out Face3 Face)
    {
        Face = new Face3();

        var args = Input.Split(' ');
        if (args.Length != 4) return false;

        bool success = true;

        success = success && int.TryParse(args[1], out Face.V1);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[2], out Face.V2);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[3], out Face.V3);

        if (!success) return false;
        return true;
    }
}       

public struct Face4 : IFace
{
    public int V1;
    public int V2;
    public int V3;
    public int V4;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("4 {0} {1} {2} {3}", V1, V2, V3, V4);
    }

    internal static bool TryParse(string Input, out IFace Face)
    {
        Face4 face = new Face4();
        bool b = TryParse(Input, out face);

        Face = (IFace)face;
        return b;
    }

    internal static bool TryParse(string Input, out Face4 Face)
    {
        Face = new Face4();

        var args = Input.Split(' ');
        if (args.Length != 5) return false;

        bool success = true;

        success = success && int.TryParse(args[1], out Face.V1);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[2], out Face.V2);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[3], out Face.V3);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[4], out Face.V4);

        if (!success) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Update:** According to @Heslacher answer, I implemented some changes. Since I wanted to be able to directly call `Face.TryParse` without the need of a `FaceParser` class, I changed the interface `IFace` to an abstract class `Face`. Because of that `Face3` and `Face4` are no longer `struct` but `class` now. I'm pretty happy with the solution.

Parsing the faces:

```
Face face;
if (Face.TryParse(lines[i], out face))
{
    faces.Add(face);
}
```

With:

```
public abstract class Face
{
    public static bool TryParse(string line, out Face face)
    {
        if (Face3.TryParse(line, out face)) { return true; }
        if (Face4.TryParse(line, out face)) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Face3 : Face
{
    public int V1;
    public int V2;
    public int V3;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("3 {0} {1} {2}", V1, V2, V3);
    }

    new internal static bool TryParse(string input, out Face face)
    {
        face = null;

        var args = input.Split(' ');
        if (args.Length != 4) return false;

        Face3 parsedFace = new Face3();
        bool success = true;
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[1], out parsedFace.V1);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[2], out parsedFace.V2);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[3], out parsedFace.V3);

        if (!success) return false;

        face = parsedFace;
        return true;
    }
}

public class Face4 : Face
{
    public int V1;
    public int V2;
    public int V3;
    public int V4;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("4 {0} {1} {2} {3}", V1, V2, V3, V4);
    }

    new internal static bool TryParse(string input, out Face face)
    {
        face = null;

        var args = input.Split(' ');
        if (args.Length != 5) return false;

        Face4 parsedFace = new Face4();
        bool success = true;
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[1], out parsedFace.V1);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[2], out parsedFace.V2);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[3], out parsedFace.V3);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[4], out parsedFace.V4);

        if (!success) return false;

        face = parsedFace;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** So this is more like a code review (you have deleted your question to early on http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but it should address your question.

---

Based on the [nameing guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) input parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing.

---

I don't see a reason, why you have overloaded `TryParse()` methods for the `Face3` and `Face4`.

Setting the passed input parameter `face` (naming guidelines) = `null` will make it possible to return early without assigning any new object to the parameter.

In the way you had created a new `Face3` the passed in `IFace` would have been initialized also if the `TryParse()` returned `false`.

This

```
public struct Face3 : IFace
{
    public int V1;
    public int V2;
    public int V3;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("3 {0} {1} {2}", V1, V2, V3);
    }

    internal static bool TryParse(string input, out IFace face)
    {

        face = null;

        var args = input.Split(' ');
        if (args.Length != 4)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Face3 currentFace = new Face3();
        bool success = true;
        success=success && int.TryParse(args[1], out currentFace.V1);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[2], out currentFace.V2);
        success = success && int.TryParse(args[3], out currentFace.V3);

        if (!success)
        {
            return false;
        }
        face = currentFace;
        return true;
    }

}
```

will just work, also without this

> ```
> IFace face = new Face3();  // ugly: I need to instanciate the face bevore I can use "out face"
> ```

---

By adding a `FaceParser` class which can be private and a static `TryParse()` method like

```
private class FaceParser
{
    public static bool TryParse(string line, out IFace face)
    {
        if (Face3.TryParse(line, out face)) { return true; }
        if (Face4.TryParse(line, out face)) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
}
```

which if it is private should be contained in the class where you are adding to the faces, your initial example how you parse the lines can be simplified to

```
foreach (string line in faceLines)
{
    IFace face; 
    if (FaceParser.TryParse(line, out face))
    {
        faces.Add(face);
    }
}
```

---

It seems that you use the `IFace` interface only as a marker interface. Adding a `ToString()` method to an interface is somehow superfluous, because each object already contains an overridable `ToString()` method. So you can simplify your interface to

```
public interface IFace {}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer - I deleted the question from code review because I think it is more concrete question for this specific problem then a general ask for a review... I'm still not entiry sure where I should have put it.

Comment: If the code in question is working and is returning the expected results and you aren't asking to add new features, it is **on topic** at code review.

Comment: That sounds like a good rule of thumb - I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

A *normal* parser will work through all the tokens, starting at the first and let the flow of control be determined by the tokens read.

In your case a (global) parser would read the first int, then decide if it continues with the "face3" or "face4" part of the code, read more ints on the way and return a `Face3` or an `Face4` instance at the end of line.

So a general outline for such a parser would be:

```
getNextToken();
switch(currentToken)
{
    case Face3Start:
        getface3();
        break;
    case Face4Start:
        getface4();
        break;
}
```